# How to use proxies with seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests, proxy, seleniumbase

I am trying to use a proxy with seleniumbase but i get:
You are using an unsupported command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors. Stability and security will suffer.(at the starting chrome page)
(after opening site)Site couldnt be reached whatismyip.com took too long to respond.
but the code works fine when i dont have a proxy

```py
from seleniumbase import SB
with SB(uc=True, proxy="IP:PORT") as sb:
    sb.sleep(10)
    sb.driver.get("https://whatismyip.com")
    sb.sleep(10)
```

And its not that the ip and port are invalid because im checking and making sure they work before using them

```py
import requests
proxies = {"http": "http://IP:PORT"}
response = requests.get("http://ipinfo.io/json", proxies=proxies)
print(response.json())
```

using this code, could someone help?

edit: maybe ips are different and some work for sb and some dont even if they work for requests and i just need to try with sb until i find working ones? idk

Answer (score 0):

The warning about the --ignore-certificate-errors flag is common when using Chrome with Selenium. This usually doesn't prevent the browser from working but indicates that Chrome might not behave as expected.

I checked your Code with my Proxy, and it works totally fine. Try another Proxy

Comment: could you tell me what proxy list you use? all of them give This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at https://whatismyip.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED or the other error

Comment: I tried the proxies from webshare. The format is IP:PORT and it totally works fine for me

Comment: This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
i get this with the free ones but they say the free proxies and paid ones are the same on webshare? which are you using free or paid?

Comment: there are some logs in the activity so its connecting but it doesnt work

Comment: Hard to say what the Problem is. I use paid Proxies, but it shouldnt really matter.